# ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have set android path as follows

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/shamsher/Documents/android-sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platforms
```

and also run source `~/.bash_profile` but still getting `ANDROID_HOME` is not set and **android** command **not** in your PATH.

Comment: Have you logged out and logged back in? If you run `echo $ANDROID_HOME` in a terminal, what response do you get?

Comment: When I do echo $ANDROID_PATH I got "/Users/shamsher/Documents/android-sdk"

Answer (score 0):

After you run set your path, what is the result from running the following commands:

```
echo $PATH
which android
ls /Users/shamsher/Documents/android-sdk
ls /Users/shamsher/Documents/android-sdk/tools
ls /Users/shamsher/Documents/android-sdk/platforms
```

Comment: Your path looks correct, and the which command shows it's finding android in the path.

If you have this in your profile, it should get loaded on login. I would recommend restarting your computer, it's possible whatever window is trying to launch the android tools doesn't have the new profile loaded.

Answer (score 0):

**Verify your paths** and check if you are able to run `adb command` from anywhere.

*for example*, on Windows I have set

**ANT_Home:** `C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.4`

**Java_Home**: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60`

**ANDROID_HOME:** `C:\Android\AndroidSDK\sdk`

**path**`:.;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;`